# Can't get Perl web service running using WSDL::Generator

Tags: perl, soap, wsdl

I have been trying for two weeks to create a web service in Perl (with [`WSDL::Generator`](https://metacpan.org/module/WSDL%3a%3aGenerator)) and call it with a client written in Perl.

Now I try the examples provided with the library specializes in WSDL: [`Soap::Lite`](https://metacpan.org/module/Soap%3a%3aLite)
but I get an error that keeps appearing

```
404 file not found at c.PL at line 7.
```

Can you help me solve it?

Here is my code:

`WorldFunctions.pm` (C:\Perl\SOAP-Lite\WorldFunctions.pm) : the class

```
package WorldFunctions;
    sub new { bless {}, shift; }
    sub Hello { my ($s, $name) = @_;
            return 'Hello, ' . $name . "\n";
    }
    sub GoodBye { my ($s, $name) = @_;
            return 'Goodbye, ' . $name . "\n";
    }
```

`a.pl` (C:\Perl\SOAP-Lite\a.pl): to create the WSDL file of the class WorldFunctions.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use WSDL::Generator;
my $init = {
        'schema_namesp' => 'http://localhost/world/WorldFunctions.xsd',
        'services'      => 'WorldFunctions',
        'service_name'  => 'WorldFunctions',
        'target_namesp' => 'http://localhost/world',
        'documentation' => 'Simple Hello World SOAP Service.',
        'location'      => 'http://localhost/world'
};
my $w = WSDL::Generator->new($init);
WorldFunctions->Hello('Joe');
WorldFunctions->GoodBye('Joe');
print $w->get(WorldFunctions); # Returns the WSDL code for a specific class
open(TOTO,"<a.wsdl");
close(TOTO);
open(TOTO,">a.wsdl");
print TOTO $w->get(WorldFunctions);
close(TOTO);
```

`c.pl` (C:\Perl\SOAP-Lite\c.pl): perl client WSDL file

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use DBI();
use CGI;
use SOAP::Lite;
my $service = SOAP::Lite-> service('file:a.wsdl');   
print "test retour : |".$service-> Hello('Joe')."|";
```

Knowing that I use a local server (with WAMP server) and I copied into my directory WorldFunctions.pm localhost / world.

Here is the WSDL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions name="WorldFunctions" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" targetNamespace="http://localhost/world" xmlns:tns="http://localhost/world" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsdl="http://localhost/world/WorldFunctions.xsd">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://localhost/world/WorldFunctions.xsd">
            <xsd:element name="GoodByeRequest" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="GoodByeResponse" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="HelloRequest" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="HelloResponse" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="GoodByeRequest">
        <part name="GoodByeRequestSoapMsg" element="xsdl:GoodByeRequest"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GoodByeResponse">
        <part name="GoodByeResponseSoapMsg" element="xsdl:GoodByeResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="HelloRequest">
        <part name="HelloRequestSoapMsg" element="xsdl:HelloRequest"/>
    </message>
    <message name="HelloResponse">
        <part name="HelloResponseSoapMsg" element="xsdl:HelloResponse"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="WorldFunctionsWorldFunctionsPortType">
        <operation name="GoodBye">
            <input message="tns:GoodByeRequest" />
            <output message="tns:GoodByeResponse" />
        </operation>
        <operation name="Hello">
            <input message="tns:HelloRequest" />
            <output message="tns:HelloResponse" />
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="WorldFunctionsWorldFunctionsBinding" type="tns:WorldFunctionsWorldFunctionsPortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
            <operation name="GoodBye">
                <soap:operation style="document" soapAction=""/>
                <input>
                    <soap:body use="literal"/>
                </input>
                <output>
                    <soap:body use="literal"/>
                </output>
            </operation>
            <operation name="Hello">
                <soap:operation style="document" soapAction=""/>
                <input>
                    <soap:body use="literal"/>
                </input>
                <output>
                    <soap:body use="literal"/>
                </output>
            </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="WorldFunctions">
        <documentation>
            Simple Hello World SOAP Service.
        </documentation>
        <port name="WorldFunctionsWorldFunctionsPort" binding="tns:WorldFunctionsWorldFunctionsBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost/world"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: Are you sure the files you're trying to access are actually there? Can you load them in a GUI browser?

Comment: sorry Brian, i am late to answer you ! but the files are placed at the rigth place and they are accecible

Comment: I'm stuck on another problem: when I execute the code that follows, it will display the error "Could not find or load mod_perl at C :/ Perl / site / lib / SOAP / Transport / HTTP.pm line 741 "

but I installed the module successfully mod_apache2

Here's the code:
`code`#!/usr/bin/perl
use SOAP::Transport::HTTP;
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Apache
    -> dispatch_to('WorldFunctions')     
    -> handle;
 
package WorldFunctions;
sub new { bless {}, shift; }`code`

Comment: In the perldoc for `WSDL::Generator` it states "**WSDL doesn't works only on perl 5.6 and not 5.8. UNIVERSAL::AUTOLOAD is broken in perl 5.8 and it is used by Class::Hook upon wich WSDL::Generator depends.**" Not quite sure what the author means but which version of perl are you using?

Comment: i use Perl v5.12.4 : the last stable version

Comment: Ok, have you successfully generated `a.wsdl` then? If so, could you include it in your question because I can't generate it using your `a.pl`? Thanks.

Comment: i have succesfully generate the Wsdl file ! i will add it in the question ! but the problem is in the call of this WSDL file !

Comment: Take a look at [XML::Compile::SOAP](http://metacpan.org/module/XML::Compile::SOAP) - it is generally much better at generating code from a WSDL, and has a support mailing list and irc channel as well.

Comment: Even though the line numbers doesn't add up, it looks as if `my $service = SOAP::Lite-> service('file:a.wsdl');` or the following line could be the trigger. See if this is the case so you can corner the issue.

Comment: It's not clear whether this problem is still active, either in the original sense (c.pl error) or a new sense (failing to load mod_perl). I suggest you either kill the question or update it to tell us the exact state of your problem. That way, we can either help you or move on. Thankyou

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are not mapping `http://localhost/world` to the SOAP handler that can handle the request, hence you are getting a 404 for that URL.

You need to configure apache so there is something at that URL.

http://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP::WSDL::Server::Mod_Perl2